# Django best practice for a site that submit jobs and polls results to the cloud

Tags: ajax, django, azure, asynchronous, cloud

I'm trying to figure out an optimal way to do this for a site that acts as a frontend to Azure. Let's say user wants to create a VM:

1) User submits job

2) Job gets submitted to Azure immediately but takes about 3 minutes to get results back.

3) I want user to submit and go on on with their business (i.e. no waiting) and the DOM to update automatically with the result when it's received.

Things I've tried:

1) Celery to schedule the task -> saves result to DB -> JavaScript polls DB every so often and update DOM

2) JavaScript runs an AJAX that talks to a view that talks to Azure via API to see if job is done. If done, save result to DB and update DOM

Issues with

1) I really don't like this method of relying on another service and adding more complexity. Main problem is that Celery is not reliable, it may run or it may queue. I also have to worry about Celery getting an up to date db data when it finally gets to the task

2) Works but the DB doesn't get updated til user actually queries the data. Also seems like too much DB reading/writing.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Main problem is that Celery is not reliable

Care to explain? It'll queue when the amount of queued tasks simultaneously exceed the amount of celery workers. So you can have more than one celery servers, with each one having multiple celery workers to process the enqueued tasks.

Now, to solve your polling issue, you can use websockets. https://github.com/django/channels

So you can do the following:

- User gets connected via websocket using Channels automatically when he opens the specific webpage or after he submits the job.
- User submits the job.
- Job gets enqueued to your message broker.
- Celery workers auto polls the broker and execute the task. The workers will execute tasks asynchronously.
- After the completion of the task, return the results via the reply channel of that user or via a group (more info if you read through the documentation).

While the user is using your webapp, you just keep the websocket connection opened and listening to the websocket new message event in JS.

Comment: Yes apparently I didn't read the manual carefully enough. I need to set the concurrency argument when starting the worker. I was working on this all day and now Celery seems to working perfectly. Channels looks interesting, thanks for that.